# Can you nest HTML forms?

Tags: html

Is it possible to nest HTML forms like this

```
<form name="mainForm">
  <form name="subForm">
  </form>
</form>
```

so that both forms work? My friend is having problems with this, a part of the `subForm` works, while another part of it does not.

Comment: He is setting up a cart, where the update quantity is inside of the form that keeps track of totals.  

I personally wouldn't do that, but he is running into problems getting that to work.

Comment: Seems like he'd be better off using Javascript to copy values from one form to the other, rather than trying to nest them. I don't think the nesting will work.

Answer (score 548, accepted):

In a word, no. You can have several forms in a page but they should not be nested.

From the [html5 working draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element):

> **4.10.3 The `form` element**
>
> **Content model:**
>
> Flow content, but with no form element descendants.

Comment: Chances are this is a .net app (which wraps a <form> tag around everything).  Any time you try to nest forms, there is a design flaw somewhere.  Ususally you want two forms next to each other, wrapped in a single DIV for styling purposes only.

Comment: I agree with the answer, but to ask another, why not? Why does HTML not allow for nesting forms? To me, it appears to be a limitation that we would be better off without. There are many examples where using nested forms would be easier to program (i.e. using an upload photo form with a profile edit form).

Comment: @Nilzor he's not asking whether or not it can't be done, he's asking WHY not. I agree; nesting forms is actually really useful. So if you have a one page app with tabs, each tab is its own form (so you can submit it to save progress), and they're all wrapped in a form, which you can submit to save everything. Makes sense to me.

Comment: I agree with what others have said.  This limitation seems arbitrary and harmful.

Comment: So we need HTML 5.1 with nested forms.

Comment: There is no problem I believe with nesting forms if you are submitting those forms with AJAX. I believe the OP is talking about an actual postback, no?

Comment: The problem with nested forms is the form architecture within HTML, where action within that form leads to a submit event. The question gets hair about what needs to be submitted. You may have several fields within a form, or several forms within a div, but it doesn't really make sense to have forms within a form. If content goes together, it's all one form; if content is submitted separately, it's really separate forms that don't need an outer form.

Comment: Could you explain to me what is flow? Thanks

Comment: @RafaelAndrade Elements belonging to the flow content category typically contain text or embedded content.

Comment: Another difficulty is that in the DOM elements have a form property which is the form they belong to. So you can't have elements belonging to more than one form which they would in the nested form.

Comment: @aroth why do you say harmful?

Comment: Because it puts an arbitrary restriction on how the markup language can be used.  In a markup language that is seldom syntax-checked or validated and where different browsers tend to accommodate different levels of incorrect/non-standard syntax anyways.  And rules out certain structures that could be beneficial in certain edge cases (some examples of which are noted in other comments, above).  It seems both more sensible and more _useful_ for nested `form` elements to be allowed.

Comment: Whilst this answers the question directly. There's a better way. See @Creative's answer using the form attribute on input elements.

Comment: With declarative formats like VueJS, nested forms can be useful. For example, you may have a parent element (form) that knows how to save the form. However you may wish to wrap this around repeating elements and then transmit an event to those children which then each know how to save themselves. Yes, you can do this without nested forms but not as elegantly. You can also prevent unwanted event bubbling using event modifiers.

Comment: Funny thing is; if you build the forms, using `js` with `document.createElement`and append it inside the other form, it works. It seems that it only doesn't work when rendering from the `html` directly. It's not consistent.

I'm here because stuff in my app were jumping around when hydration was happening. It was because of this. Kinda of a disappointing behavior.

Now I'm gonna go empty all of my <form>(s) and use `form` attribute everywhere, because you never know which component will be inside which.

Answer (score 214):

The **HTML5** `<input> form` attribute can be the solution.
From http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_form.asp:

> 1. The form **attribute** is new in HTML5.
> 2. Specifies which `<form>` element an `<input>` element belongs to. The value of this attribute must be the id attribute of a `<form>` element in the same document.

**Scenario**:

- input_Form1_n1
- input_Form2_n1
- input_Form1_n2
- input_Form2_n2

**Implementation**:

```
<form id="Form1" action="Action1.php" method="post"></form>
<form id="Form2" action="Action2.php" method="post"></form>

<input type="text" name="input_Form1_n1" form="Form1" />
<input type="text" name="input_Form2_n1" form="Form2" />
<input type="text" name="input_Form1_n2" form="Form1" />
<input type="text" name="input_Form2_n2" form="Form2" />

<input type="submit" name="button1" value="buttonVal1" form="Form1" />
<input type="submit" name="button2" value="buttonVal2" form="Form2" />
```

[Here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=form-attribute) you'll find browser's compatibility.

Comment: Just to point the browser-support table: https://caniuse.com/#feat=form-attribute

Resuming - it works everywhere(Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Egde, Safari, Android browser...) except IE (including latest by now v11).

Comment: @cliff-burton, what is the difference here? I just can see inputs outside of the form. It still would need JS to submit both forms at the same time. Wouldn't it?

Comment: Uh, it's been a long time since the last time I used this but I think JS is not required for submitting the form. Provided that the `<input type="submit"` is linked to its `<form>` that specifies an `action`, the `<input />`(s) linked to that same `<form>` will be used in that request

Comment: Yes, it works and saved our app.

Answer (score 101):

**It is possible** to achieve the same result as nested forms, but without nesting them.

HTML5 introduced the form attribute. You can add the form attribute to form controls outside of a form to link them to a specific form element (by id).

https://www.impressivewebs.com/html5-form-attribute/

This way you can structure your html like this:

```
<form id="main-form" action="/main-action" method="post"></form>
<form id="sub-form"  action="/sub-action"  method="post"></form>

<div class="main-component">
    <input type="text" name="main-property1" form="main-form" />
    <input type="text" name="main-property2" form="main-form" />

    <div class="sub-component">
        <input type="text" name="sub-property1" form="sub-form" />
        <input type="text" name="sub-property2" form="sub-form" />
        <input type="submit" name="sub-save" value="Save" form="sub-form" />
    </div>

    <input type="submit" name="main-save" value="Save" form="main-form" />
</div>
```

The form attribute is supported by all modern browsers. IE does not support this though but IE is not a browser anymore, rather a compatibility tool, as confirmed by Microsoft itself: https://www.zdnet.com/article/microsoft-security-chief-ie-is-not-a-browser-so-stop-using-it-as-your-default/. It's about time we stop caring about making things work in IE.

https://caniuse.com/#feat=form-attribute
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#attr-fae-form

From the html spec:

> This feature allows authors to work around the lack of support for
> nested form elements.

Comment: what is the difference here? I just can see inputs outside of the form. It still would need JS to submit both forms at the same time. Wouldn't it?

Comment: @sdlins No, the idea is to style main-component and sub-component as how you want them to look, nested. The actual 2 form tags will be invisible. Each submit button will trigger it's respective form submit. No javascript is required.

Comment: if you want trigger only one *or* other form, ok. But how would it resolve when you need trigger the &quot;parent&quot; form *with* its child forms as it was one and without js?

Comment: @sdlins that's not what this question is about. The question is about 2 different forms, but have them nested. I'm wondering why you want to have 2 forms but still 1 submit function? Can't you just have 1 form then? You'll indeed have to resort to javascript for something as weird as that :P

Comment: yeah, you're right, that isn't the OP question. I will post my own. Thank you!

Answer (score 93):

The second form will be ignored, see the [snippet](http://opensource.apple.com/source/WebCore/WebCore-855.7/html/HTMLParser.cpp) from WebKit for example:

```
bool HTMLParser::formCreateErrorCheck(Token* t, RefPtr<Node>& result)
{
    // Only create a new form if we're not already inside one.
    // This is consistent with other browsers' behavior.
    if (!m_currentFormElement) {
        m_currentFormElement = new HTMLFormElement(formTag, m_document);
        result = m_currentFormElement;
        pCloserCreateErrorCheck(t, result);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 45):

Plain html cannot allow you to do this. But with javascript you can be able to do that.
If you are using javascript/jquery you could classify your form elements with a class and then use serialize() to serialize only those form elements for the subset of the items you want to submit.

```
<form id="formid">
    <input type="text" class="class1" />
    <input type="text" class="class2">
</form>
```

Then in your javascript you could do this to serialize class1 elements

```
$(".class1").serialize();
```

For class2 you could do

```
$(".class2").serialize();
```

For the whole form

```
$("#formid").serialize();
```

or simply

```
$("#formid").submit();
```

Answer (score 33):

If you're using AngularJS, any `<form>` tags inside your `ng-app` are replaced at runtime with `ngForm` directives that are designed to be nested.

> In Angular forms can be nested. This means that the outer form is valid when all of the child forms are valid as well. However, browsers do not allow nesting of `<form>` elements, so Angular provides the `ngForm` directive which behaves identically to `<form>` but can be nested. This allows you to have nested forms, which is very useful when using Angular validation directives in forms that are dynamically generated using the `ngRepeat` directive.  ([source](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form))

Comment: This was the answer i was looking for :) And yes it does makes sense to nest form because if you have multiple tabs but you want to perform validation on just one tab, then with nested form you can do that.

Comment: Is it the same for webcomponents?

Answer (score 14):

Another way to get around this problem, if you are using some server side scripting language that allows you to manipulate the posted data, is to declare your html form like this :

```
<form>
<input name="a_name"/>
<input name="a_second_name"/>
<input name="subform[another_name]"/>
<input name="subform[another_second_name]"/>
</form>
```

If you print the posted data (I will use PHP here), you will get an array like this :

```
//print_r($_POST) will output :
    array(
    'a_name' => 'a_name_value',
    'a_second_name' => 'a_second_name_value',
    'subform' => array(
      'another_name' => 'a_name_value',
      'another_second_name' => 'another_second_name_value',
      ),
    );
```

Then you can just do something like :

```
$my_sub_form_data = $_POST['subform'];
unset($_POST['subform']);
```

Your $_POST now has only your "main form" data, and your subform data is stored in another variable you can manipulate at will.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 13):

As Craig said, no.

But, regarding your comment as to *why*:

It might be easier to use 1 `<form>` with the inputs and the "Update" button, and use copy hidden inputs with the "Submit Order" button in a another `<form>`.

Comment: I made my cart page like that, he just went a different way and didn't want to change it.  I wasn't positive if his method was all that valid either.

Answer (score 10):

> Note you are not allowed to nest FORM elements!

http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/forms.html

https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/changes.html#h-A.3.9 (html4 specification notes no changes regarding nesting forms from 3.2 to 4)

https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/changes.html#h-A.1.1.12 (html4 specification notes no changes regarding nesting forms from 4.0 to 4.1)

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/ (html5 specification notes no changes regarding nesting forms from 4 to 5)

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#association-of-controls-and-forms comments to "This feature allows authors to work around the lack of support for nested form elements.", but does not cite where this is specified, I think they are assuming that we should assume that it's specified in the html3 specification :)

Comment: I have no idea why you'd post on a question that has been answered 3 and a half years, but more problematic is linking to HTML3 which hasn't been a recommendation for a long time.

Comment: It's a reference to how long the underlying question has been answered, which I believed to be constructive. Also I found the tact-free "Note you are not allowed to nest FORM elements!" within the spec to be humorous.

Comment: This is a problem because I have to insert an API that is a form and because .net app (which wraps a <form> tag around everything). How do you overcome this issue.

Comment: In the HTML5 spec https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-form-element, about form element: "Content model: Flow content, but with no form element descendants."

Answer (score 10):

You can also use formaction="" inside the button tag.

```
<button type="submit" formaction="/rmDog" method='post' id="rmDog">-</button>
```

This would be nested in the original form as a separate button.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question but this just helped me solve another problem I was having so giving upvote

Comment: ignore above (wouldn't let me edit after 5 minutes...hmm).  huge help here - exactly mapped onto what I was attempting to do this morning.  this is why we all love SO

Comment: There is a `formmethod` attribute for the button — https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_formmethod.asp

Answer (score 6):

A simple workaround is to use a iframe to hold the "nested" form.
Visually the form is nested but on the code side its in a separate html file altogether.

Comment: Time's up for iframes

Answer (score 5):

Even if you could get it to work in one browser, there's no guarantee that it would work the same in all browsers. So while you might be able to get it to work *some* of the time, you certainly wouldn't be able to get it to work *all* of the time.

Answer (score 4):

About nesting forms: I spent 10 years one afternoon trying to debug an ajax script.

my previous answer/example didn't account for the html markup, sorry.

```
<form id='form_1' et al>
  <input stuff>
  <submit onClick='ajaxFunction(That_Puts_form_2_In_The_ajaxContainer)'>
  <td id='ajaxContainer'></td>
</form>
```

form_2 constantly failed saying invalid form_2.

When I moved the ajaxContainer that produced form_2 `<i>outside</i>` of form_1, I was back in business. It the answer the question as to why one might nest forms. I mean, really, what's the ID for if not to define which form is to be used? There must be a better, slicker work around.

Comment: LOLOLOLOL "I spent 10 years one afternoon"...totally get it. So funny.

Answer (score 4):

Although the question is pretty old and I agree with the @everyone that nesting of form is not allowed in HTML

But this something all might want to see this

where you can hack(I'm calling it a hack since I'm sure this ain't legitimate) html to allow browser to have nested form

```
<form id="form_one" action="http://apple.com">
  <div>
    <div>
        <form id="form_two" action="/">
            <!-- DUMMY FORM TO ALLOW BROWSER TO ACCEPT NESTED FORM -->
      </form>
    </div>
      <br/>
    <div>
      <form id="form_three" action="http://www.linuxtopia.org/">
          <input type='submit' value='LINUX TOPIA'/>
      </form>
    </div>
      <br/>

    <div>
      <form id="form_four" action="http://bing.com">
          <input type='submit' value='BING'/>
      </form>
    </div>
      <br/>  
    <input type='submit' value='Apple'/>
  </div>  
</form>
```

JS FIDDLE LINK

http://jsfiddle.net/nzkEw/10/

Comment: Great example.

I was sure nested forms did work in the past, but i discovered, that nowdays browser seem to have a problem with that.

My big question is,,, WHAT is your hack ? Why are your nested forms working, and my nested form ends at the first closing form tag?
Can you explain this more clearly ?

Answer (score 4):

Use empty form tag before your nested form

Tested and Worked on Firefox, Chrome

Not Tested on I.E.

```
<form name="mainForm" action="mainAction">
  <form></form>
  <form name="subForm"  action="subAction">
  </form>
</form>
```

EDIT by @adusza: As the commenters pointed out, the above code does not result in nested forms. However, if you add div elements like below, you will have subForm inside mainForm, and the first blank form will be removed.

```
<form name="mainForm" action="mainAction">
  <div>
      <form></form>
      <form name="subForm"  action="subAction">
      </form>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: when i tried this on chrome it outputs this
<form name="mainForm">
  </form>
  <form name="subForm">
  </form>

Comment: Did you tried with submit button. I'm used this method many times and always worked.

Comment: This is a violation of the specification and using it is begging for future problems.

Comment: Newer webkit versions just remove the nested form elements.

Comment: This only seems to work when the `innerHTML` of `mainForm` is set via JavaScript (i.e. ajax). Just having this snippet in an HTML file will not result in nested forms: the empty form tag will terminate the outer one, and `subForm` will be just after `mainForm` (tested on Chrome 86 and Firefox 80). Strangely, when setting `innerHTML`, only the first nested form is removed, and the rest are kept nested.

Comment: Update, you don't need ajax if there is another element, like a div between the outer and the inner forms. Weird.

Answer (score 4):

While I don't present a solution to nested forms (it doesn't work reliably), I do present a workaround that works for me:

Usage scenario: A superform allowing to change N items at once. It has a "Submit All" button at the bottom. Each item wants to have its own nested form with a "Submit Item # N" button. But can't...

In this case, one can actually use a single form, and then have the name of the buttons be `submit_1`..`submit_N` and `submitAll` and handle it servers-side, by only looking at params ending in `_1` if the name of the button was `submit_1`.

```
<form>
    <div id="item1">
        <input type="text" name="foo_1" value="23">
        <input type="submit" name="submit_1" value="Submit Item #1">
    </div>
    <div id="item2">
        <input type="text" name="foo_2" value="33">
        <input type="submit" name="submit_2" value="Submit Item #2">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submitAll" value="Submit All Items">
</form>
```

Ok, so not much of an invention, but it does the job.

Answer (score 2):

Really not possible...
I couldn't nest form tags...
However I used this code:

```
<form>
    OTHER FORM STUFF

    <div novalidate role="form" method="post" id="fake_form_id_0" data-url="YOUR_POST_URL">
        THIS FORM STUFF
    </div>
</form>
```

with `{% csrf_token %}` and stuff

and applied some JS

```
var url = $(form_id).attr("data-url");

$.ajax({
  url: url,
  "type": "POST",
   "data": {
    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}',
    'custom-param-attachment': 'value'
  },
  success: function (e, data) {
      if (e.is_valid) {
         DO STUFF
      }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Before I knew I wasn't supposed to do this I had nested forms for the purpose of having multiple submit buttons. Ran that way for 18 months, thousands of signup transactions, no one called us about any difficulties.

Nested forms gave me an ID to parse for the correct action to take. Didn't break 'til I tried to attach a field to one of the buttons and Validate complained. Wasn't a big deal to untangle it--I used an explicit stringify on the outer form so it didn't matter the submit and form didn't match. Yeah, yeah, should've taken the buttons from a submit to an onclick.

Point is there are circumstances where it's not entirely broken. But "not entirely broken" is perhaps too low a standard to shoot for :-)

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot have a nested form. Instead you can open up a Modal that contains form and perform Ajax form submit.

Answer (score 0):

Today, I also got stuck in same issue, and resolve the issue I have added a user control and
on this control I use this code

```
<div class="divformTagEx">

</div>

<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litFormTag" Visible="false">
'<div> <form  style="margin-bottom: 3;" action="http://login.php" method="post" name="testformtag"></form> </div>'</asp:Literal>
```

and on PreRenderComplete event of the page call this method

```
private void InitializeJavaScript()
{
        var script = new StringBuilder();
        script.Append("$(document).ready(function () {");
        script.Append("$('.divformTagEx').append( ");
        script.Append(litFormTag.Text);
        script.Append(" )");
        script.Append(" });");
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "nestedFormTagEx", script.ToString(), true);
    }
```

I believe this will help.